# How can I convert an AVI file to something the iPod can view?

Tags: video, conversion, ipod-touch, avi

My son received a DVD with some AVI files of his soccer game. (I think they're from a Sharp camcorder, but I'm not 100% sure of that).

How can I convert them to a format that he can view on his iPod Touch?

I have a Mac, Linux and Windows machines available, so any platform-specific recommendations are welcome.

Comment: If you're Mac is fairly recent, it should already have iMove installed. I would try that first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is a free cross-platform program and converts just about anything to anything including iPod/iPhone.

Comment: I heard handbrake stopped supporting avi's. Was that just for outputting avi's?

Comment: AVI is still a supported input format - but yes, as of version 0.9.4 it no longer supports writing output in the AVI container.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mencoder : http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/MPlayer.html#mencoder

Answer (score 0):

There are many free video converters available. Some of the most easy ones are Format Factory and Freemake Video converter. Both are very good software. Format Factory also supports audio convertion and image convertion too.

Both these will convert almost all type of video formats to any video format.